# Linq join two string list using contains

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am having two lists as follows:

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string>( new string[]{
  "United States",
  "Brazil",
  "India",
  "Canada"
});

List<string> l2 = new List<string>( new string[]{
 "Asia:India",
 " North America:Canada",
 "EU:Germany"
}) ;
```

how to list all items from `l2` in which contains the string in `l1` using Linq Lambda?

**Desired Output**

```
"Asia:India"
"North America:Canada"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of countries to look for, I suggest using `HashSet<string>` (it has better Contains time compexity, `O(1)` vs `O(N)`):

```
  HashSet<string> countries = new HashSet<string>() {
    "United States",
    "Brazil",
    "India",
    "Canada",
  };
```

To create `countries` from `l1`:

```
  HashSet<string> countries = new HashSet<string>(l1);
```

Then you can put a simple *Linq*:

```
  var result = l2
    .Where(item => countries.Contains(item.Substring(item.IndexOf(':') + 1)));
```

You data has inner structure: `Area:Country` which we can exploit with a help of `Substring` and `IndexOf`

**Demo:**

```
  var l1 = new List<string>() { 
    "United States", 
    "Brazil", 
    "India", 
    "Canada", 
    "Congo",  // <- My special test case 
  };
  
  var l2 = new List<string>() { 
    "Asia:India", 
    "North America:Canada", 
    "EU:Germany", 
    "Africa:Democratic Republic of Congo" 
  };

  HashSet<string> countries = new HashSet<string>(l1);

  var result = l2
    .Where(item => countries.Contains(item.Substring(item.IndexOf(':') + 1)));

  Console.Write(string.Join("; ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  Asia:India; North America:Canada
```

Note abscence of unwanted `Africa:Democratic Republic of Congo`: `Congo` and `Democratic Republic of Congo` are *different* states.

**Edit:** Linq `Join` solution

```
 var result = l2.Join(
   l1, 
   item => item.Substring(item.IndexOf(':') + 1), 
   item => item, 
  (left, right) => left);
```

Comment: plus one for the detailed explanation
BTW, how to do it using Linq **Join** ?

Comment: @Biju Soman: For Linq `Join` solution, please, see my edit

Answer (score 3):

For each item in the second list, check if there is any item in the first list that is part of the item:

```
l2.Where(i => l1.Any(j => i.Contains(j));
```

Note that this can be slow for large lists.

Comment: Possible counter example: `l1 = { "Brazil", "India", "Congo"} ; l2 = { Asia:India", "Africa:Democratic Republic of Congo"}`. Here we have unwanted `"Africa:Democratic Republic of Congo"`, since `"Africa:Democratic Republic of Congo"` *contains* `Congo` which is *different* country

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = l2.Where(x => l1.Any(l => x.Contains(l)));
```

if the `l1` is a large list you can use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) instead of l1 to improve the time.

Alternative way you can split each element of `l2` by `:`

```
var answer = l2.Where(x => l1.Contains(x.Split(':')[1]));
```

Comment: In general case, only the second option seems to be correct one: in `l1 = { "Brazil", "India", "Congo"} ; l2 = { Asia:India", "Africa:Democratic Republic of Congo"}` we don't want `"Africa:Democratic Republic of Congo"` be in `answer`

Comment: thats true if that case happens